# Is it possible to have a unique key condition based on another value?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, unique-constraint

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID, STRING_VALUE, ENUM_VALUE, CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER
```

I'd like to create a condition that won't allow two identical ENUM_VALUEs, but only if their ID is also the same.

For example:

```
1  BLUE    4  6   --> Good
2  BLUE    4  6   --> Good
3  BLUE    4  6   --> BAD
3  GREEN   4  6   --> BAD
```

Is there any way to create such a constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a unique constraint on the 2 columns.

```
ALTER TABLE schemaName.tableName ADD CONSTRAINT
        uniTableName UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(ID, ENUM_VALUES)
```

Comment: doesn't that make ID and ENUM_VALUES unique? and if it doesn't, the reason this works is because we treat ID and ENUM_VALUES as one "object"?

Comment: It makes the combination of ID and ENUM_VALUES unique.  It's similar to creating a `NONCLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY` on the table but you can create more than one of them.  IE you can only have one `PRIMARY KEY` but you can have multiple `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS`.